# Cannot add foreign key constraint - Works for one constraint, but not the other

Tags: sql, popsql

I have created the following tables (there are more attributes, but they weren't relevant to the question):

```
CREATE TABLE PathData(
    path_outer_id int,
    path_inner_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY(path_outer_id, path_inner_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Node(
    node_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    max_path_outer_id int,
    max_path_inner_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY(node_id)
);
```

And tried connecting them with the following commands:

```
ALTER TABLE Node ADD CONSTRAINT fk_1
FOREIGN KEY(max_path_outer_id) REFERENCES PathData(path_outer_id);

ALTER TABLE Node ADD CONSTRAINT fk_2
FOREIGN KEY(max_path_inner_id) REFERENCES PathData(path_inner_id);
```

However, while fk_1 worked, fk_2 leads to the Cannot add foreign key constraint error and I can't figure out why, since it does the exact same thing as fk_1 does, except for the other attribute. I've tried searching what caused this, but I can't seem to find anything similar.

I thought maybe it could be related to inner_id being declared a PK after outer_id, but that doesn't seem logical.

Comment: Is this MySQL with InnoDB engine?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. The language I'm using is SQL, but I'm writing such commands on PopSQL.

Comment: If it is MySQL as a backend, your issue is "in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order" (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-restrictions)) and there isn't such an index on `path_inner_id`. It's probably worth adding `INDEX (path_inner_id)` to your `PathData` table to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if I understand the issue, since `path_outer_id` works and it's not been explicitly declared as an index, as the manual talks about. But thanks, your solution did work. Could you expand on why there was a difference?

Comment: There is an index in `PathData` on `path_outer_id` which has `path_outer_id` first in the list: `PRIMARY KEY(path_outer_id, path_inner_id)`. Note you could also work around this with `FOREIGN KEY(max_path_outer_id, max_path_inner_id) REFERENCES PathData(path_outer_id, path_inner_id)` as there is a matching index in `PathData` for that too.

Comment: Understood. I'll try keeping the second way of declaring the foreign keys in mind, since it feels more intuitive than the other solution. Many thanks.